# Xcode - Grouping JSON data in sections

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I am fetching data from an SQL database using JSON.
The data includes a day ( Mon - Sunday ) and tasks.
If I want to group all tasks per day in sections how do I do this exactly?

I'm looking at the NumberOfSections in tableview method now but I can't seem to figure it out.
There are only 7 days in a week so I know I have to return 7 sections, but how do I put the right data under the right day of week?
Can anyone put me on the right track?
This is how I fetch the data:

```
- (void)retrieveData {
//Pass the username to a string so we can use it further
DataManager* dm = [DataManager sharedInstance];
NSString *leefgroep = (NSString*)[dm objectForKey:@"leefgroep"];
NSLog(@"%@",leefgroep);


NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.php?leefgroep=%@&",leefgroep];


NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];


jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:
             kNilOptions error:nil];

//setup Array

todoArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//loop through jsonArray
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    //create objects

    NSString * cID =[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * cDay=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"day"];
       NSString * cHour=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"hour"];
       NSString * cTask=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"task"];


    //add object to Array

    [todoArray addObject:[[Todo alloc]initWithday:cDay andID:cID andhour:cHour andtask:cTask]];



}


[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

The returned JSON data is like this:

```
{"id":"1753","day":"3","hour":"08:00:00","task":"go to the shop"},{"id":"1755","day":"4","hour":"08:00:00","task":"change tires"}
```

Thanks in advance

Dresse

Comment: It would be easier to assist you if you provided some code describing how you're loading data out of your database and in which structure you have retrieved it.

Comment: Hello Ian

I have posted some code. I use a method in which I add objects to an array. I also posted the JSON output I see on the webserver. In my cellforRowAtIndexPath I can simply put the values in the tableview cell. But cant seem to figure out how to group them.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you may fetch complete data as an list of objects, where each object contains the day and again a list of tasks about that day. Then you may return the element count of the main list as section count, and the element count of each child list as row count.

```
{
 [
  {
   day : "Sun",
   tasks : [{task1}, {task2}]
  },
  {
   day : "Mon",
   task : [{task1}, {task2}, {task3}]
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any modification to the code you've posted, you could split the data into sections in your table view datasource methods like so:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  NSUInteger rows = 0;
  for (Todo *todo in todoArray) {
    if (todo.day == section) rows++;
  }
  return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  Todo *cellTodo = nil;
  NSUInteger row = 0;
  for (Todo *todo in todoArray) {
    if (todo.day == indexPath.section) {
      if (row == indexPath.row) {
        cellTodo = todo;
        break;
      }
      row++;
    }
  }
  // Construct your UITableViewCell with the data held in cellTodo.
}
```

---

There are better ways of arranging your data, but without knowing your full list usage scenarios for the data, it's hard to pick a best one. This one requires the least change to your existing code.